# How do you put silverlight in a web user control

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I need to put silverlight in a web user control. How might I go about this?

Comment: The same way you put it in a normal HTML page.

Comment: About the same way as in any other piece of HTML/ASPX. What is your specific problem, what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your `<asp:Silverlight>` control to your .ascx file and reference your .xap properly.

Comment: there is no asp:Silverlight control in asp.net 4. you need to use <object> I believe

Comment: @SP - Yes. the asp:Silverlight control was deprecated after Silverlight 2.